# Not able to ban members out of the server .py cog

Tags: python, discord.py

```
            @commands.command()
            @commands.guild_only()
            @commands.has_guild_permissions(ban_members=True)
            async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
                if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
                    await ctx.send(f"You can only ban members below your role.")         
                    return
                
                
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(864083000211406849)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name} banned: {member.name}", description=reason)
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                await member.send(f"You've been banned from : `{ctx.guild}` for `reason`: {reason}.")
                await ctx.guild.ban(user=member, reason=reason)
        
            @ban.error
            async def ban_error(self,ctx, error):
                if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
                    
                    title=f"{ctx.author.mention} you do not have the required permission(s)/role(s) to run this command!"
                    await ctx.send(title)
```

So I want my code to basically kick a member that has left my server using their ID. Ive looked in to previous questions but it seems to be no help for me.

Comment: What errors are you getting with this code?

Comment: I don't think you can ban members out off the server, that makes no sense

Comment: i dont get any errors ,but carl bot seems to be able to ban members out of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting the member input to a `discord.Member`, which needs to be in the server. Instead convert it to a `discord.User`, who does not need to be in your server.

```
async def ban(self, ctx, member: discord.User, *, reason=None):
```

Please keep in mind that your top role lookup and comparison will not work when you use the `discord.User`, you will have to get the actual member beforehand, like this:

```py
server_member = ctx.guild.get_member(member.id)
if server_member != None:
    if server_member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send(f"You can only ban members below your role.")         
        return
```

Also you will get an error trying to message someone who does not share a server with your bot, or has blocked your bot etc., I would just use a try/except block for this:

```py
try:
    await member.send(f"You've been banned from : `{ctx.guild}` for `reason`: {reason}.")
except discord.errors.Forbidden:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ;-; !